# perlinstallation - includefiles

Tags: perl, include

When I build and install my own perl from the source the installation-path is /usr/local. In /usr/local/include are no files. Does it make sense to copy the files from /usr/include to /usr/local/include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not. Why would you want to do that, anyway? `/usr/include` is already part of the default include path for the relevant toolchains, e.g.

```
echo | gcc -v -x c -E -
```

Comment: I've made an error when searching a file (wrong extension) so I thought the difference is in the include-directories but now I've seen that the needed file is available in the "/usr/lib"-path but not in the "/usr/local/lib"-path.